# Why this JS destructuring assignment method works for reverse the singly linked list?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I am doing a leetcode question [reverse singly linked list](https://leetcode.com/problems/reverse-linked-list/).

I tried the following code, and see if I miss the code at place 1, it will get error on result. I understand it is because it lose the reference to `current.next`. (Thanks for this [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278017/strategies-to-reverse-a-linked-list-in-javascript).)

```
function ListNode(val) {
    this.val = val;
    this.next = null;
}
/**
 * @param {ListNode} head
 * @return {ListNode}
 */
var reverseList = function(head) {

    let current = head;
    let prev = null;
    while (current) {

        current.next = prev;
        prev = current;
        current = current.next;

        //The right one
        // let save = current.next; //1
        // current.next = prev;
        // prev = current;
        // current = save;

    }

    return prev
};
```

The problem is, I found another code showing below also works by using array destructuring assignment (the name right maybe?), but I can't understand why this work without using another variable to save the reference to the `current.next`.

```
var reverseList = function(head) {

    let current = head;
    let prev = null;
    while (current) {
        [current.next, prev, current] = [prev, current, current.next];//2
    }

    return prev
};
```

So how is the code at place 2 actually working without using another variable to save the reference to the `current.next`?

Comment: I think the destructuring assignment takes care of references by automatically swapping to a temporary variable for `current.next` against `prev`. You may want to take a look at the official ECMAScript2015 Semantics about Runtime 
 Destructuring Evaluation: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-runtime-semantics-destructuringassignmentevaluation

Comment: [MDN: Swapping variables using destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables)

Comment: [This is what the transpiled code looks like](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=NoYwrgThCmB2AuA6W0Ae8A0ACADjAbtuFHPALpYC8Wwe0hWxMCRkzSK6ZQA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.4.4&externalPlugins=)

Comment: @adiga your last comment should be the answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[current.next, prev, current] = [prev, current, current.next];` is an array destructuring syntax and it works without keeping a tempvariable explicitly because the reference is kept in an array

you can think of the above code as

```
const arr = [];
arr[0] = prev;
arr[1] = current;
arr[2] = current.next;

current.next = arr[0];
prev = arr[1];
current = arr[2]
```

where the reference of the original elements is kept within an array instead of individual variables

Answer (score 0):

Using destructuring assignment for swapping variables there is no need for temporary variables.

```
var a = 1;
var b = 3;

[a, b] = [b, a];
console.log(a); // 3
console.log(b); // 1
```

See [Swapping variablesSection with Destructuring on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables)

See ECMAScript docs linked in briosheje's answer for language specs details.