# Reverse a nested Array list Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, properties, reverse

What i want it to reverse a list from bottom to top.
I used for loop of i--, but i coudn't make it work even by using the built in Reverse() function.

**The rules are:**

1. You cannot use the built-in reverse() function.
2. null is non-existent object, you may use an empty object instead if desired.
3. Your function should be able to reverse a list of values of any type.
4. You must use at least one array to solve the problem.

**Original:**

```
var list = {
   value: 1,
      next: {
         value: 2,
         next: {
            value: 3,
            next: null     
         }
      }
};
```

**Reverse it to look like:**

```
var list = {
   value: 3,
   next: {
     value: 2,
     next: {
       value: 1,
       next: null
     }
   }
};
```

**Example Test Case:**

```
function reverseList(list) {
    // return reversedList;
}

Arguments: { value: 1, next: { value: 2, next: { value: 3, next: null } } };
Returns: { value: 3, next: { value: 2, next: { value: 1, next: null } } };

Arguments: { value: "a", next: { value: "b", next: { value: "c", next: null } } };
Returns: { value: "c", next: { value: "b", next: { value: "a", next: null } } };
```

Comment: lucky you can't use `reverse` ... since there's absolutely no arrays in that data

Comment: This is called reversing a linkedlist and is just a coding interview problem that should never have to be used in real life. If this is a real problem in some code you wrote, you are using the wrong data structure. If you are trying to get help on a coding interview, implement the algorithm here(https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/)

Comment: Thank you @KyleDePace, ya, it is a question i was given to solve. Do you think it can be solved easily? maybe with the use of one or two functions?

Comment: `Reverse a nested Array list Javascript` as Jaromanda already said, there's no array  anywhere in that data structure. That's a linked list. where did you get the term `nested Array list` from? `4. You must use at least one array to solve the problem.` why? that's unnecesary overhead.

Comment: "it is a question i was given to solve." - Then it is either an interview Question or School learning task. Either way this is a task for you to research. I would suggest you could start by reading about Object.keys()

Answer (score 0):

there is no array so you cant inbuilt `reverse` function. also searching for *reverse a linked list* on SO gave me [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23278017/strategies-to-reverse-a-linked-list-in-javascript) which I am referencing in code snippet.

```js
var reverseLinkedList = function(linkedlist) {
  var node = linkedlist;
  var previous = null;

  while (node) {
    // save next or you lose it!!!
    var save = node.next;
    // reverse pointer
    node.next = previous;
    // increment previous to current node
    previous = node;
    // increment node to next node or null at end of list
    node = save;
  }
  return previous; // Change the list head !!!
}
var list = {
  value: 1,
  next: {
    value: 2,
    next: {
      value: 3,
      next: null
    }
  }
};
var linkedlist = reverseLinkedList(list);
console.log(JSON.stringify(linkedlist));
```